# Locked file that I can't remove

Tags: terminal, file, catalina

Long story short, I downloaded a file as a replacement for an app that no longer works on Catalina (macOS 10.15). This file is locked, and I cannot `chmod` it to let me unlock it. Even `sudo` fails.
[image]
[image: Terminal]

I need to delete this file. How can I delete it? It doesn't seem I can...

Comment: [This page](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/immutableflags.html) may help you find a solution.

Comment: Thanks @IconDaemon, but that didn't work, and neither did [this](https://www.cnet.com/news/managing-locked-files-in-os-x/). Are there any other ways you know of?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure out the problem.

First I used `ls -laO` which showed the flags for all files. It turns out that both `schg` and `uchg` had been set on the files. To override those, I did:

```
sudo chflags nouchg /Applications/Karabiner-Elements.app
sudo chflags noschg /Applications/Karabiner-Elements.app
```

This unlocked both flags, and allowed me to delete the files.

Thank you all for your help.